# Plots savefig works at the top level, but not within a function?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to write some command line Julia programs to generate and save plots.

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia
using Plots
pyplot()
plot(1:100,1:100)
savefig("foo.png")
```

But this doesn't:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia
using Plots
function main(args)
    pyplot()
    plot(1:100,1:100)
    savefig("foo.png")
end
main(ARGS)
```

Failing with

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::PyPlot.Figure, ::Symbol)
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 21855, while current world is 21864.
```

Any thoughts or pointers appreciated please!

UPDATE - Thanks for all the suggestions. This is a work around:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia
using Plots
function main(args)
    plot(1:100,1:100)
    savefig("foo.png")
end
pyplot()
main(ARGS)
```

Comment: Likely a bug in Plots.jl, please open an issue: https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues (I *think* the fix is to change https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/blob/2067b7044503cefb559c105a5aeb08aaa8b1c861/src/output.jl#L123 to `Base.invokelatest(func, plt, fn)` but haven't tested.)

Comment: Another thing to test is to move `pyplot()` outside the function. That function call essentially loads the PyPlot library, and is thus equivalent to a `using Package` statement in some sense (which you don't do in local scope like that, it is an error in fact), that will likely also fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** To my knowledge, this issue should not be present in Julia v1.0

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** This is probably more suited to a comment, but I ran out of characters.

This is the infamous "world age" issue in `Plots`. This usually shows up when you're using the `GR` backend, rather than `PyPlot`, but to my knowledge it can affect the entire `Plots` eco-system under certain circumstances.

Issue pages for this already exist [here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/895), [here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/1047), and [here](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/745) (and I think there is actually one or two more). There are several people actively working on fixing this, but it's proving to be very tricky to eradicate completely.

As a work-around for now, try calling `savefig` on any random plot generated outside a function, *then* call the function(s) that contains the plotting that you want to do. This works on my system, hopefully it will work for you too.